# How could I send a String to arduino uno from jetson nano through rosserial?

Tags: ros, arduino-uno, nvidia-jetson-nano

Actually this value is calculated  by Jetson nano and send to arduino for further calculations of angles and for rotating the servos. Does anyone have any clue ?

I tried using ROS-Melodic but can't understand how these kind of communication is possible.

Comment: What do you mean? have you tried understanding serial communication?

Comment: If you question is on how to use serial communication on ROS-Melodic, then it has nothing to do with Arduino. You need to have better explanation on the problem you are facing?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentaion](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial)? It includes a step-by-step guide for exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can confirm that [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino) works even on arduino nano but it very very limited on space